# Axis2 Rampart: No user value in the rampart configuratio

Tags: java, windows, linux, apache-axis, rampart

I have a Java program running an axis2 1.5.3 with rampart 1.5 client working perfectly fine on my linux using openjdk. When I ported it over to Windows 7, it works on some machines but does not on most with the error "No user value in the rampart configuration"! This is the same regardless if I recompile the code or not. I also tried duplicating the java environment such as java version, ant version, system arch to no avail. Can anyone suggest a solution?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what is the exact reason for this issue. but this exception is thrown at the **BindingBuilder.java** class which is in the **rampart-core module** and **package org.apache.rampart.builder**
please try to debug following methods

- addUsernameToken() method
- getSignatureBuilder() method

there this exception occurs when rampart cannot read user values from the policy.xml file.

hope this might be helpful.

suresh..